# In Angular, how can I run a small script on each component that gets loaded? (diagnostic purposes)

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to run certain diagnostic lines of Javascript as I develop that will console log the `alt` attribute on all `<img>` tags in the HTML, for instance.  This is purely for testing and will not go to production of course.  On a single component I would normally run this within the `ngAfterContentInit()` and/or `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle hooks, so it would run this script whenever the images in the HTML have been loaded and rendered.

The JS would just be something simple like `getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('alt')`, but how can I run this each time a component is displayed, so I can check these kinds of things without adding an import to each individual component?  Is there something I can do in the AppModule for instance that controls the components that are loaded?  I would like to run these kinds of scripts on dynamically/lazily loaded components too, if that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom directive for this purpose, Define global img selector in custom directive. Then use ElementRef class to access image alt attributes value.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, isDevMode, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: 'img',
})
export class ImgDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isDevMode) {
      console.log(this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute('alt'));
    }
  }
}
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fj7g46?file=src/app/img.directive.ts)**

Comment: Great solution!  I didn't know about `isDevMode` from @angular/core either!  Thank you.